# How to implement info bar about filter setting in sap.m.table?

Tags: sapui5

[image: Responsive Table]
[image: View Setting]

In fiori guideline of [View Setting](https://experience.sap.com/fiori-design-web/view-settings-dialog/) and [Responsive Table](https://experience.sap.com/fiori-design-web/responsive-table/), there is a info bar shows the filter setting. How to implement it?

It looks like a `sap.m.MessageStrip`, but there are only [five kinds of MessageType](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.core.MessageType.html) in MessageStrip(Error, Information...), seems no such color suits for this bar. Should I overwrite this color?

In this [Demo](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/explored.html#/sample/sap.m.sample.TableColumnWidth/preview), message strip is put above the Table, but in design, it seems to put between table title and column, how to implement it?

I've tried this:

```
<Table>
    <headerToolbar>
        <Toolbar>
            <Title id="tableHeader" text="title"/>
            <!--BUTTONS-->
            <VBox>
                <MessageStrip
                    text="Filtered By:"
                    type="Information"
                    showCloseButton="true"
                    showIcon="false">
                </MessageStrip>
            </VBox>
        </Toolbar>
    </headerToolbar>
</Table>
```

But it looks like this: 
[image]

Comment: Are you refering to the 'facet filter' component ? https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/explored.html#/sample/sap.m.sample.FacetFilterLight/preview

Comment: That uses `sap.m.List` as the base, not `sap.m.Table` which is a different control with different layouts. Here's the list base toolbar sample: https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/sample/sap.m.sample.ListToolbar/preview

Comment: @Jorg,  I tried it in `sap.m.Table`, it's working! It is exactly matched with the design! Thanks very much.  I think it is because that List and Table both extends sap.m.ListBase. https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.m.ListBase/methods/getInfoToolbar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is called `infoToolbar`, not `infoBar`...

```
<Table>
    <infoToolbar>
            <Toolbar
                active="true"
                press="handleInfobarPress" >
                <Label text="Filtered By: " />
                <ToolbarSpacer />
                <core:Icon
                   tooltip="Reset filter"
                   src="sap-icon://sys-cancel"
                   class="size2"
                   color="white" 
                   press="onResetFilters">
                </core:Icon>
            </Toolbar>
    </infoToolbar>
    <headerToolbar>
        <Toolbar>
            <Title id="tableHeader" text="title"/>
            <!--BUTTONS-->
        </Toolbar>
    </headerToolbar>
</Table>
```

infoToolbar is implemented in `sap.m.ListBase` as Aggregations: https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.m.ListBase

Both `sap.m.List` and `sap.m.Table` borrowed these aggregations/methods from `sap.m.ListBase`.